# Заполнение массива случайными числами в Си

Tags: c, случайные-числа

Изучая массивы я пришёл к вопросу, как можно создать массив и заполнить его абсолютно рандомными значениями? В интернете есть ресурсы, в которых приводится код для решения этой задачи, но к сожалению без объяснений, а хотелось бы понять какие функции за это отвечают, сколько есть различных методов и какими способами лучше всего это делать, чтобы действительно был рандом.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/398ax69y(v%3Dvs.140) и https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/rand?view=vs-2017

Comment: Для UNIX https://stackoverflow.com/a/2572373/7485582 и Windows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191335/windows-equivalent-of-dev-random

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если С++ - то там теперь в стандарт входит надежная и эффективная библиотека `<random>`. Если на C - то надо использовать только встроенный генератор `rand()` или писать свой, опираясь, скажем, на Кнута. Конечно, это не *абсолютно* случайные числа, а псевдослучайные.

Ваш вопрос не очень точен - например, какое распределение чисел в матрице должно быть? Равномерное, нормальное или какое еще?

Обычно это выглядит как

```
int r[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) r[i] = rand();
```

Ну, или, скажем, для случайных чисел в диапазоне от `A` до `B` (только `B-A+1` не должно превышать `RAND_MAX`) -

```
r[i] = rand()%(B-A+1) + A;
```

Если уточните свой вопрос - можно будет уточнить ответ :)